# How do you make holes in a cylinder sharp using subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modeling

I am making high poly model for a gun using subdivision surface modifier, in the pic you can see the barrel with a hole in it but the control loops deform the curvature of the barrel as in it isn't round anymore. How do you make holes in a cylinder sharp using subdiv? Or you shouldnt use subdiv?[image]

Comment: You need more holding loops. There are also problems with the cylindrical part, because as you mentioned, some of the loops there are flattening the cylinder into an octagon(?). LaserMan's answer is on the right track, although a bit simplistic. Subdividing too much could introduce different problems. Maybe do like one more level of subdivision first and then refine by adding more holding loops. Or you can create a circular 16-gon, and using vertex snapping, align existing geometry to it. It's challenging because I know what I would do, but I can't put all of it into words comprehensively.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at a lot of similar questions on here, and it seems the only answer is to fill in your holes, then do your subsurf modifier and apply it, and then cut out your holes afterwards.